# Any other DNS resolvers other than Google or/and OpenDNS

Tags: debian, networking, systemd, dns, systemd-networkd

I am on Debian testing/stretch. I am currently using Google DNS resolvers. There is OpenDNS as well but are there any others that people would recommend apart from these two -

```
[$] cat /etc/systemd/network/wired.network

[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10%
```

This is a desktop/workstation. It doesn't travel at all. I need options as I don't want google recording all my activities and any other options would be good.

Comment: You can also put a recursive nameserver on loopback and use that (bonus: AXFR authoritative zones into that to help avoid those being spoofed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Unix or Linux.

Comment: What about OpenNIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to http://public-dns.info/ and have a look if one fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`namebench`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/namebench/downloads)

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/namebench/namebench-1.3.1-source.tgz
tar xvf namebench-1.3.1-source.tgz
```

change directory to `namebench-1.3.1-source` then run the benchmark test

```
./namebench.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether this was for a laptop (which travels to different networks) or a server (which exists at a fixed place on a network).

You also didn't mention *why* you wanted to consider options.

You can consider using the name servers provided by your Internet Service Provider. What's interesting about your ISP as a choice is that you have existing legal relationship with them, improving your standing in the case of a problem with the service quality.

If your primary concern is performance, then [namebench](https://code.google.com/archive/p/namebench/downloads) to find the faster providers from your location and re-run the bench every few months to confirm you are still getting the fastest service.